# How to delete Ubuntu from boot menu in UEFI-startup sources

Tags: uefi

I had Ubuntu on my computer, but I don't use Ubuntu anymore.

I still have the Ubuntu option on my computer's boot menu in UEFI.

How do I delete this crappy useless boot option with Windows and without Linsucks?

Answer (score 2):

Step 1
Insert Ubuntu live CD or Ubuntu Bootable USB. Restart and boot into Ubuntu live session.

Step 2
Open Terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install efibootmgr
```

Step 3
Don’t close terminal type following command to remove bios boot menu entry.

```
sudo efibootmgr
```

you will able to see different menu entries.Look for menu entry with name *ubuntu* or *linuxmint* and see last number or character before * sign next to boot name.

For example: my bios boot menu entries were :

```
Boot000A* ubuntu
```

Or

```
Boot0009* linuxmint
```

Type in terminal to remove these entries (for me it is 9 for you it can be any other  number) :

[image: screenshot]

```
sudo efibootmgr –b  9  –B
```

if it is a alphabet

```
sudo efibootmgr  -b  A  –B
```

Done . Hooray !!   :)

Type `sudo efibootmgr -v` in terminal to crosscheck.

If you don't see the entries Ubuntu or Linux Mint you have successfully removed them  from boot menu.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

download and install easyBCD non commercial version. Here is the [link](http://neosmart.net/download.php?id=1)

Here you can edit the boot menu easily.

If you have installed ubuntu in a seperate ext4 parttion.. first delete that partition using windows(right click my computer and click manage)
Then restart your computer using a windows7 DVD. use recovery options to fix MBR